# Why is the open graph API returning NULL when I upload a video?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've been uploading video to the Facebook open graph API using the following code. Something seems to have changed, as the API is now returning NULL every single time. I can't see what I'm doing wrong; can someone help?

(Note: $local_filename below verifiably exists, and is a video. CURL is also working, as we use it to connect to other services.)

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $config->facebook_appid,
    'secret' => $config->facebook_secret,
    'cookie' => true,
    'fileUpload' => true,
));

try {
    $facebook->setAccessToken($user->facebook_token);
    $fbvideo = $facebook->api('/me/videos','POST',
        array(
            'source' => '@' . $local_filename, 
            'title' => 'Some title', 
            'description' => 'Some description',
            'message' => 'Uploaded with ...'));
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to catch the exception or print the result?

```
try {
    $facebook->setAccessToken($user->facebook_token);
    $fbvideo = $facebook->api('/me/videos','POST',
        array(
            'source' => '@' . $local_filename, 
            'title' => 'Some title', 
            'description' => 'Some description',
            'message' => 'Uploaded with ...'));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $res = $e->getResult();
}

print_r($fbvideo);
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to post to different url that is https://graph-video.facebook.com/ not 
https://graph.facebook.com/

don't know how and if that map on $facebook->api, but you can post by using Graph API

there is an article and sample code here somewhere https://developers.facebook.com/blog/archive#2011